# How can I get multiple string parameters in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd need to catch a url like this:

```
localhost:3000/mypage/name/123/234/345/456
```

I know I can use a Route like this:

```
<Route path='/mypage/:pagename/:ids' component={MyComponent}/>
```

I don't know how to get in ids an array of ints (I know in reality they are strings). Note the number on items after name can change.

any help? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use only one route parameter for ids.

So your url must be like this:

```
localhost:3000/mypage/name/123,234,345,456
```

And you can access this ids like this:

```
const ids= this.props.match.params.ids;  //if functional component, props...

const idsIntArray = ids.split(',').map(Number);   // [123, 234, 345, 456]
```

**As an alternative**, it would be more suitable to send your ids as query string.

So your url can be:

```
localhost:3000/mypage/name?ids=123,234,345,456
```

And in your component you can get the ids query string, and parse it into an array.

The easist way to parse query string is using a package called `query-string`.
After you install it with `npm i query-string` and importing you can read the ids query string and convert it to int array like this:

```
import queryString from 'query-string'


const ids= queryString.parse(this.props.location.search.ids);  //if functional component, props...

const idsIntArray = ids.split(',').map(Number);   // [123, 234, 345, 456]
```

With this, in your Route definition there is no need to put ids in the url:

```
<Route path='/mypage/:pagename' component={MyComponent}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using query paramater for this case

```
    <Route path='/mypage/:pagename' component={MyComponent}/>
```

and URL can be `localhost:3000/mypage/name?id=123&id=234&id=345&id=456`

This way you can get query params array inside component and workd on that data